# Unable to upgrade npm from 1.4.28 to latest (2.2)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I'm using stable version of node on Ubuntu 14.04. (installed via PPA) When I was trying to upgrade some packages like yo, I got the error below:

```
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: yo@1.4.2
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"1.4.28","node":"0.10.35"}

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "update" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ekrem
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ekrem/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

When I hit `(sudo) npm update -g npm`, here's the result I got:

```
npm@2.1.3 /home/ekrem/.node/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/npm
```

After hitting `npm -v`

```
1.4.28
```

I've also cleared all files under `~/.npm`, cleared cache, reinstall components I needed but nothing changes. In addition;

```
➜  ~  which node
/usr/bin/node
➜  ~  which npm 
/usr/bin/npm
➜  ~  less ~/.npmrc
prefix = ~/.node
```

I've checked similar issues on the net but there's nothing close to mine.

UPDATE:

I've removed nodejs; cleared files under `~/.node` & `~/.npm` (as @johns has suggested) installed using first method of the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814). Here are updated outputs:

```
➜  node -v
v0.10.35
➜  npm -v 
1.4.28
➜  which node
/home/ekrem/local/bin/node
➜  which npm 
/home/ekrem/local/bin/npm
➜  npm update -g npm 
# returns nothing
➜  ~  npm config get prefix
/home/ekrem/.node
```

Comment: What about `ls -l $(which npm)`?

Comment: I tried `npm update -g npm` and successfully updated npm to 2.2.0.

Comment: @JohnS result of the command: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Ara 25 02:41 /usr/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

Comment: now `cat /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json | grep \"version\"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue and found this post. The way I got npm to work after several tries is to remove all the npm 'node_module' folders and delete any npm config files particularly the .npmrc file in your home directory.

Then I ran 'sudo apt-get purge nodejs'.

I went to the installer and reinstalled nodejs using the following:

```
'curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh'
```

then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Finally I ran:

```
npm update -g npm
```

There were issues posted about a bug in that 'update' function, but it seemed to work for me and I got from 1.4 to 2.7.

I hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me

navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs with cmd.exe and then run the installation without -g:

```
npm install npm
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Ubuntu as I've described in the question above.

Comment: This approach does work on windows... You need to run the `cmd` prompt as an administrator and depending on your system your `nodejs` installation might be under `C:\Program Files\nodejs` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`

Comment: this worked for me on a mac, with the exception that i had to add the global flag, so i used "npm install -g npm"

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to do the following steps to go from **npm@1.4.28** to **npm@3.2.0** (currently the latest):

`curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

This line may trigger some errors like:

`Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'`

If so, simply run:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/npm` (or the specified directory display in the error)

From there:

`sudo npm install -g npm@3.0-latest`

And now the

`npm -v`

successfully display a beautiful: `3.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of comments out there about "npm update -g" being broken and to not use it for now:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6247

I'd trying resetting or reinstalling npm and then go from there - a fresh reinstall of npm should be relatively painless and fix things:

https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#if-your-npm-is-broken

Comment: I think that discussion is about running `npm update -g` without any package name.

Comment: @John I've already tried re-installing npm with the script on the page you gave, with sudo it says "It worked" at last but `npm -v` still returns `1.4.28`. I wish it could be still installable as seperated.

Comment: @ekremkaraca Have you taken this one step further and uninstalled via apt-get remove or apt-get purge and then re-installing?

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to @ThinkBonobo, but all I had to do was run the update straight from npmjs.org. From a freshly provisioned instance:

```
$curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
$sudo apt-get install nodejs
$npm -v
1.4.28
$curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
$npm -v
2.7.3
```

No other steps were requried.